# Problems with python super method

Tags: python

I have this problem:
my super class is:

```
class Regressionb(object):
    def __init__(self, Datamatrix, targets):
        self.X = Datamatrix
        self.y = targets

    def theta_X_product(self, theta, X):         
        return self.add_column_zero(X).dot(theta)

    def add_column_zero(self, X):
        m = len(X)
        return np.concatenate((np.ones([m,1],1]), X), axis = 1)
```

than, my child class:

```
from Regressionb import *

class LinearRegressionb(Regressionb):
    def __init__(self, Datamatrix, targets):
        Regressionb.__init__(self, Datamatrix, targets)
        #tryed also with        super().__init__(Datamatrix, targets)


    def hypothesis(self, theta):         
        return lambda X : Regressionb.theta_X_product(self, theta, X)
        #also tryed       return lambda X : super().theta_X_product(theta, X)
```

than I run from the console:

```
X = np.matrix([  [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24], [31, 32, 33, 34]])    
theta = np.matrix([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]).T

from LinearRegressionb import *
linear = LinearRegressionb(X, y)
h = linear.hypothesis(theta)
```

for which I receive the error:

```
hypothesis() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I dont see how I give 2  parameters. Where is my mistake??

Comment: In fact, you are passing two arguments (`self` and `theta`). Are you sure that the child class is located in the file `LinearRegressionb.py`?

Comment: what do you mean. the child class IS LinearRegressionb. defind by:
class LinearRegressionb(Regressoinb)... init  etc..
how should I call than hypothesis from the console? what do I give for self?

Comment: When you do `linear.hypotesis(theta)`, you are doing `LinearRegressionB.hypothesis(linear, theta)`. In other words `Class.method(instance, ...)`. Since you are doing `from LinearRegressionb import *`, I would expect that your class is located in the file `LinearRegressionb.py`.

Comment: `return lambda X: self.theta_X_product(theta, X)`  super is only needed to call a method that has been overridden.

Comment: Are you using `Python 2` or `Python 3`?

Comment: can't figure out how you can get this error from these listngs: chances are you are calling classes/functions from other files than the ones you think you are. Note thqat in Python you don't need to have one single class per file, neither need to have the class named as the file - these are java restrictions.

Comment: Your code wouldn't be valid if you got your classes to work anyways... Did you at least try writing this out without a class first? It looks like you are using some numpy methods incorrectly.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your child class should look like:

```
class LinearRegressionb(Regressionb):
    def __init__(self, Datamatrix, targets):
        super(LinearRegressionb, self).__init__(Datamatrix, targets)


    def hypothesis(self, theta):         
        return lambda X : super(LinearRegressionb, self).theta_X_product(theta, X)
```

-- Edit --

Agreed, that, though super might not be the best thing to do since `hypothesis` has not been overridden, but unnecessary or not, that is up to the programmer. The point here was IMHO, how to call a method from the parent class, and the proper syntax of using super, which I demonstrated. Not sure why I'm being downvoted for that.

Comment: Calling `super()` in `hypothesis` is completely unnecessary -- `theta_X_product` has not been overridden.

Comment: and what about the __init__? also avoid super there?
is my the child class ink __init__ correct?

Comment: `__init__` has been overridden, so there you need to call `super`.

Comment: @EthanFurman I added my reply to your comment as an edit to my answer

Comment: It would be unusual for `method_A` to directly call `super.method_B` directly and not `self.method_B`, and is generally bad advice.  Your use of `super` in `__init__` is correct.